# Bootstrap alignment problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap layout with a navbar at the top. For some reason, the container that's supposed to appear underneath the navbar is not being pushed down below the navbar. You can see this in action on https://searchlightpro.us Can you tell me where I'm going wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `margin-top` to the container that is underneath the navbar. Set it to `5em` or so and this should push it down so the navbar isn't covering it.

Comment: Thank you very much!